# Emacs on Windows 8.1 with font scaling for 4K monitor

Tags: emacs, fonts, windows-8.1

I'm using Emacs on a Windows 8.1 computer with a 4K resolution monitor.  I scaled up all the Windows fonts to 200%, since otherwise it is difficult to read.  In most applications, the scaled fonts look great, but in Emacs they look fuzzy and pixelated.  If I set the Windows font scaling to 100% and choose a larger font for Emacs, then the Emacs font looks great, but then it is difficult to read text in other applications.  Is there any way to set the Windows font scaling to 200% and also have a font in Emacs that looks good?

Answer (score 15):

Right click on the `emacs.exe` binary, go to Properties > Compatibility.  Then check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".  This disables the automatic scaling performed by Windows 8.1, like the 100% setting that you attempted, but only for Emacs.  You will then have to configure Emacs for larger fonts as before, and everything should look okay.

The disadvantage of this method is that Emacs will not rescale properly like other applications when switching monitors or connecting remotely.  Perhaps a future version of Emacs will be resolution-aware, resolving the problem.

Comment: How is the scaling now on emacs? Are the issues that you mentioned already fixed on emacs?

Comment: It appears to be resolution-aware now.